# My <div class = content "> overlap with nav-justified

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a nav-justified list for my login page because you can connect with a login / password or guest mode.
The problem is that if I click Login, Guest is still displayed and if I like reclique Guest.

Code :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ app.request.basepath }}/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ app.request.basepath }}/css/templatemo_main.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/icon" href="{{ app.request.basepath }}/favicon.ico"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ app.request.basepath }}/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Nautilus - {% block title %}Authentification{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <h2 class="text-center">{{ block('title') }}</h2>
  {% if error %}
   <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <strong>Erreur lors de l'authentification !</strong> {{ error }}
   </div>
  {% endif %}
 
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
     <li class="active"><a href="#invite" data-toggle="tab">Invité</a></li>
     <li><a href="#connexion" data-toggle="tab">Connexion</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 
  <div class="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-pane fade in active connexion" id="invite">
    <div class="container">
     <div id="content">
      <div class="well">
       <form class="form-signin form-horizontal" role="form" action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
          <input type="text" name="_username" value="Invite" class="form-control" required>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
          <input type="password" name="_password" class="form-control">
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Connexion</button>
         </div>
        </div>
       </form>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab-pane fade connexion" id="connexion">
   <div class="container">
    <div id="content">
     <div class="well">
      <form class="form-signin form-horizontal" role="form" action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
       <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
         <input type="text" name="_username" placeholder="Entrez votre login" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
         <input type="password" name="_password" class="form-control" required placeholder="Entrez votre mot de passe">
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Connexion</button>
        </div>
       </div>
      </form>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <script src="{{ app.request.basepath }}/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ app.request.basepath }}/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ app.request.basepath }}/js/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ app.request.basepath }}/js/templatemo_script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Image :
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgnN8.jpg)

Comment: Didn't understand! Pas compris :)

Comment: Look at the picture. In fact I have a nav-justified (guest, Connection), to select the connection method and the login form. But instead overlap to disable and give way to that which has selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your mark-up.

In the div with class tab-content you have place all the tab-pane divs. The one with #connexion was outside.

Here is the correct markup.

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ app.request.basepath }}/css/main.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ app.request.basepath }}/css/templatemo_main.css">
     <link rel="icon" type="image/icon" href="{{ app.request.basepath }}/favicon.ico"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ app.request.basepath }}/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="container">
     
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
         <li class="active"><a href="#invite" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Invité</a></li>
         <li><a href="#connexion" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Connexion</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tab-content">
             
       <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active connexion" id="invite">
        <div class="container">
         <div id="content">
          <div class="well">
           <form class="form-signin form-horizontal" role="form" action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
              <input type="text" name="_username" value="Invite" class="form-control" required>
             </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
              <input type="password" name="_password" class="form-control">
             </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Connexion</button>
             </div>
            </div>
           </form>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>

       <div  role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="connexion">
        <div class="container">
         <div id="content">
          <div class="well">
           <form class="form-signin form-horizontal" role="form" action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
              <input type="text" name="_username" placeholder="Entrez votre login" class="form-control" required>
             </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
              <input type="password" name="_password" class="form-control" required placeholder="Entrez votre mot de passe">
             </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Connexion</button>
             </div>
            </div>
           </form>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>

      </div>
      
      
     </div>

     <script src="{{ app.request.basepath }}/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="{{ app.request.basepath }}/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="{{ app.request.basepath }}/js/Chart.min.js"></script>
     <script src="{{ app.request.basepath }}/js/templatemo_script.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Yes JS and CSS are loaded.
Yes Guest displays correctly when loading the page as it is not in active connection.
By cons, if after you click Connection, Connection appears well BUT Guest (what they overlap). And as if I reclique after clicking on Guest Connect.

Comment: the tabs tags have an class active; See how it's assigned.

Comment: Also pay attention to the HTML Markup. Have a look here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Comment: Yes, that was the solution. Thank you.